# Cannot create a file when that file already exists when using Directory.Move

Tags: c#

I am trying to move the directory from one location to another location on the same drive. I am getting "**Cannot create a file when that file already exists**" error. Below is my code.

could any one suggest on this?

```
        string sourcedirectory = @"F:\source";
        string destinationdirectory = @"F:\destination";

        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(sourcedirectory))
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(destinationdirectory))
                {
                  Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
                }
                else
                {
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationdirectory);
                  Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log(ex.message);
        }
```

Comment: What would you want if files exist in destination, override? or merge

Comment: i dont have any folder or file in the destinatin, i just want to move my source folder into destination folder

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As both of the previous answers pointed out, the destination Directory cannot exist. In your code you are creating the Directory if it doesn't exist and then trying to move your directory, the Move Method will create the directory for you. If the Directory already exists you will need to Delete it or Move it.

Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourcedirectory = @"C:\source";
        string destinationdirectory = @"C:\destination";
        string backupdirectory = @"C:\Backup";
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(sourcedirectory))
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(destinationdirectory))
                {
                    //Directory.Delete(destinationdirectory);
                    Directory.Move(destinationdirectory, backupdirectory + DateTime.Now.ToString("_MMMdd_yyyy_HHmmss"));
                    Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
                }
                else
                {
                    Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx

"This method throws an IOException if, for example, you try to move c:\mydir to c:\public, and c:\public already exists. You must specify "c:\public\mydir" as the destDirName parameter, provided that "mydir" does not exist under "c:\public", or specify a new directory name such as "c:\newdir"."

Comment: i have tried by giving the destination as F:\destination\source, but the same error is getting.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create Directory first, it will throw IO Exception, if destination directory exists, `Move` method automatically creates it for you:

```
string sourcedirectory = @"F:\source";
string destinationdirectory = @"F:\destination";

if (Directory.Exists(sourcedirectory))
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(destinationdirectory))
    {
         Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
    }
}
```

More infomation of `Directory.Move`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx

Comment: If target directory exists, this code won't move the source directory's files to the target directory.

Answer (score 2):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx),

> This method throws an IOException if, for example, you try to move
>   c:\mydir to c:\public, and c:\public already exists.

But, in your method, you are creating the destination directory before you move.

So, you need to change your method from

```
if (Directory.Exists(destinationdirectory))
{
  Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
}
else
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationdirectory);
  Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
}
```

to

```
if (Directory.Exists(destinationdirectory))
{
  //delete or rename
}
Directory.Move(sourcedirectory, destinationdirectory);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(source, destination, true);
```

What it does internally is it creates the target directory if it's not exists and then it iterates over the source directory's files and moves them to the target directory. That way the problem of "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" won't happen.

You'll need to add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as a reference.